# Java Buffered Reader detecting patterns in phrases

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader

I want my program to be able to read in a file of java code and be able to identify the different methods. Is this possible to do with a buffered reader or should I be doing something different? Since methods can return any type (String/void/int/etc) and can be of many different types of modifier (private/public etc) I don't see how I can identify them easily.

```
public returnType methodName(String s){
```

How can I get my program to read that in and automatically detect that it is of the same format as:

```
private Set<String> nextstates(int newInt)
```

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206065/java-parse-java-source-code-extract-methods)

Comment: You can use the Java Development Tools (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) to get an Abstract Syntax Tree, which presents you with all the information you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to search the file for method definitions. You would just read in the file line by line using a BufferedReader for example and search in every line for matches with the regex. One possible regex is the one suggested in the following [post by Georgios Gousios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847507/3235944)